# Trigger Click Event on Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio

It's one of those days when nothing seems to work.

I want to click a row of a table and have an alert display (and a great deal more, but this is the root cause of all my other issues).

I have a VERY simple test case set up in Visual Studio 2017; here is the entire cshtml file:

```
 <table id="filterTable">
        <tr>
            <td>header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#filterTable tr').click(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried a dozen different scripts, particularly variations of the above (e.g. with and without the "(document).ready" portion) and I cannot seem to get it working.

I've seen examples of this and extremely code working and I'm at a loss for why mine won't.

I need help narrowing down what I'm doing wrong.

Let me know if any additional information would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Ok this might make you mad but I've just put it on fiddle and it's working: https://fiddle.jshell.net/j608mon4/

Comment: jQuery loaded? Try to type that in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers): `$.fn.jquery;`... It should output the jQuery vesion loaded **OR** *"$ is not defined"*.

Comment: Can you share browser source code for this page instead of cshtml file?

Comment: Tried this on codepen.io https://codepen.io/valeriavg/pen/VMpmYV all seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jquery.js  to your page to work with the jQuery

> If you used library external from the local. better The address of the
>   link is `HTTPS://...`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#filterTable tr').on('click',function () {
      alert('hello');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="filterTable">
   <tr><td>header</td></tr>
   <tr><td>value</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery library for your code. Hier is an example:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#filterTable tr').click(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="filterTable">
        <tr>
            <td>header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filterTable tr').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="filterTable">
  <tr>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```